# What does "look for an angle" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've come across it in the 12th episode of the 5th season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Rick: You shoul keep your gates close.
>
> Woman: Why?
>
> Rick: Because it's all about survival now.
>
> At any cost.
>
> People out there are always **looking for an angle**.
>
> Looking to play on your weakness.

Comment: Related question on Word Reference: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/look-for-an-angle.3301139/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Angle", in this sentence, means "a way of getting an advantage, often an illicit one."

It can also, given the situation they are in, mean "line of attack."